# Storing data in Spreadsheet instead of any database

Tags: google-app-engine, google-apps

Is it possible to use Spreadsheet has a database to store data...I don't want to use any database externally, I want to use Python, Google Apps and spreadsheet only.

For Example: using Python and Google Apps I have developed leave application  form, on submit of that form I have to store that data in to spreadsheet instead of using any database (MySql or Oracle)

If its possible give me some reference code

Thanks in advance

Comment: are you confusing google apps and google app engine?  You tagged your post with app-engine, but you if you are considering mysql then you are most likley not talking about using app engine

Answer (score 1):

Whilst storing data in a spreadsheet might seem like a good idea at first, as your application gets more complicated you may come to regret it.  If your data structures become more complicated - especially if you need relationships between tables - you'll be much better off with a database.

My advice would be to use a database and then use [The `xlwt` module](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/xlwt) to convert your data into Spreadsheet format.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you store this data internally in a flat file or database and transform the data to the spreadsheet. Doing it this way will let you change with the future. If you use google apps spreadsheet, and the api changes even slightly, you could lose data.  If you store in an xls spreadsheet, you might as well store in a flat file and export the data as that will be easier than reading/writing to a spreadsheet.

Why do you want to do it this way?

Comment: By seeing different answers posted for my question, I am going to use MySql as database, I am new to Google apps and Python , can I get steps, how to connect to database using python and Google Apps

Comment: What's wrong with using the App Engine datastore? It's a better approach than either jury-rigged solution.

Comment: I don't think the poster is actually considering app engine at all.

Comment: Yes peter I am using Google App Engine